# 0>=null -> true, 0>null -> false, 0==null -> false?

Tags: javascript, null

Open up a console for example in Chrome or Firebug. Try the following:

```js
console.log(0 >= null); /* true, so let's look closer: */
console.log(0 > null);  /* false, so it's got to be equal, right? */
console.log(0 == null); /* false again?? */
```

So, how can `0` be *greater or equal* `>=` *null* if it is neither *greater* `>` nor *equal* `==`?

Comment: I tried `console.log(0<=null);` still `true`

Comment: console.log(0<=0); // true
console.log(0<-1); //false
console.log(0<=-1); //false

Comment: [Wat!?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: "Despite the fact that null is a falsy value (i.e. it evaluates to false if coerced to a boolean), it isn't considered loosely equal to any of the other falsy values in JavaScript." http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/equals-equals-null-in-javascript.html